# Best approach to move data between SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server, data-transfer

Ok, let me explain the environment we are facing here:

We have an ASP.NET MVC 4 app that uses a SQL Server database.

This app isolates data in "projects", so when any user connects to it only can work on the data of one of this projects.

Sometimes... a group of users have to travel to remote regions for some days to retrieve data for a single project, and quite often they won't be able to have an internet connection (even mobile or satellite solutions are often out of reach).

While the displaced team works on a project, people at the office still can work on the rest of the projects (but no on the one that is abroad).

So... we are pondering the possibility of using a laptop to act as a "mobile server", where users can download the data from a specific project before travelling. While abroad, they can work against this "mobile server", update any data on their project and, when they come back, they could upload their updated data to the main server.

Our idea is to create stored procedures on both servers (main and mobile) that executes different queries to update data from a project between them, passing the project identifier as a parameter. Probably using [Linked servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) to allow main and mobile to see themselves during update operations.

Our questions here are:

- Is this a good aproach?
- Is there any other better approach that we're not seeing?
- Are there any risks we should pay attention to in this or other approachs?

Comment: `Linked servers` are well and good

Comment: YOu might want to look at replication

Comment: @HLGEM replication seems very promising, indeed. I must dig more on this. Any good resource you can recommend me to start from?

Comment: I am not a dba so I have never set up replication, I just know that it exists and roughly what it does.  YOU might think about what you want to ask about it and ask on the dba site

Comment: You can start from MSDN here are few links http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152531.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Bidirectional transaction replication so if that works for you, problem solved. I do have quite a bit of experience with data migration, including merging large data sets into software driven systems. And from that experience, replication has hurt us more than it has helped us (from a migration/merge view).

The biggest challenge in my opinion is going to be conflict resolution. I know you say that all of the data is in project specific databases, but there is no shared data at all? What about multiple remote users updating the same data? In that case you're going to need a little more than just replication.

Instead of maintaining two databases at all times (one for mobile, one as the regular in-house db), why not a system where a job is called to your main system indicating that a project needs to be prepared for "offline mode" (the job could be stored procedures or SSIS packages or straight T-SQL). Whatever the technology used, this job would copy all of the requested project data to a new database on the remote server/laptop and mark it somehow in the main database as read-only to prevent users in the office from updating that data.

Once the data is in offline mode on the remote server, the users can update and use the data as much as they want from that remote server. Then when the users get an internet connection or they are back in the office they can kick off another job that syncs the data to the main server, removes offline mode, and deletes/archives the remote database. Almost like a temporary project database.

Seriously, it sounds like a fun project.

Technologies to look at: 
SSIS (Sql Server Integration Services) - In my experience, this is extremely fast at moving data and allows you the ability to add logic to handle conflict resolution, error logic, etc. It's free (with certain Sql Server editions) and the community is huge so supporting it should be easy. SSIS is not as dynamic as some of the specialized solutions out there.

A data migration suite like Pervasive's Data Integrator - I loved this but it's expensive. You could right an entire solution in this product that could handle the processing of your data bidirectionally and like SSIS it allows for complex programming logic.

T-SQL - With a linked server you could just write straight queries (using stored procedures if you wanted). The problem here is security on the linked server. We don't use them because of this issue. [Linked Servers: Good or Bad?](http://awanderingmind.com/2009/12/05/linked-servers-good-or-bad/)

Start using some of Microsoft's built in change detection technologies right off the bat. It's harder to implement when you're already using the system. Change Data Capture (CDC) will give you a full history of the records updated while Change Tracking will give you a light-weight summary of your changes. Using either technology will make syncing the data many times easier.

Change Tracking: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933874.aspx
Change Data Capture: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx
SSIS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx
SQL Server Agent Jobs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your deep response. I'm still pondering options. Replication so far looks exactly as what we are looking for, however there are quite discourageing comments out there about using it.
As you comment, there is shared data, but it's mainly on master tables that won't be replicated (users cannot modify them). And there's only one table with actual editable data that's shared through projects. I supose that replication problems could came from there, although I think that actual conflicts should be extremely rare.

Comment: First tests with replication are being very promising, if we don't find any drawback it seems we're going this way.